# PlayFramework2: css not loading on heroku

Tags: java, css, heroku, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a play2 application and have tried to deploy it on heroku .After deployment, the application does not have styles at all. I've re-tested the application on my local/dev machine and all is working fine.

So, Could some one told me how to fix play2 issues with css ?

Comment: Have you checked with a webdevelopper console what is the problem ? Open the css page directly in a first time, and examine the result.

Comment: Please show the view which loads the CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all, I've found problem and fixed it. So, short description:
After log analysis I've found some issues in urls like next `path=/assets//stylesheets/style.css`, so, after deleting one `/` symbol from url all is started working.

*So, as conclusion , local version can work and load resources with additional `/` symbols in path but heroku cant.*